# How to make words in your TextView clickable / launch code?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, hyperlink, android-preferences

Most of the answers I see online talk about how to add `a href` tags to text so when you click a word in the text, you launch a website.

I am trying to make it so you click a word and it goes to a part of your app via Intent, scrolled down to the proper location (in this case, a specific part of my Settings/preferences page, at a specific preference tag).

Old answers talk about using getListView() to autoscroll but this is for the older framework of using PreferenceActivities (whereas now I use an Activity and invoke a PreferenceFragment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to use a [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html). To make a passage of your text clickable you could use something like this, but there are various ways how to apply a clickable span to your text.

```
    String text = textView.getText();
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);
    String passage = "xy"; // the substring you want to make clickable in the text
    int index = text.indexOf(passage); //can return -1 if passage is not in the text (ignored this for the purpose of this example)
    spannable.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            //your code here
        }
    }, index, index + passage.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannable);
```

You should somehow show the reader that the passage is clickable. Use a [UnderlineSpan](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan.html) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

To make a specific word clickable, use `SpannableString` class then use it in your text. Check this [LINK](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com.eg/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html) in the `onClick()` you can try to open activity while **passing some info** to that activity that can understand what to do, like creating a list then scroll to a specific item